# How to print out the contents of a std::vector with std::copy_n?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, stdvector, std

I want to print out the contents of a `std::vector` in C++.

Here is what I have:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  vector<int> v;
  copy_n(istream_iterator<int>(cin), 5, back_inserter(v));

  return 0;
}
```

Can I print the contents of the `std::vector` with the same method?

Comment: Yes, you can. Take a look the sample code at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator/ostream_iterator for inspiration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You need to iterate through the vector and [`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) the contents to the output stream with the help of [std::ostream_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator/ostream_iterator).

```
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
```

[See live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nL3fsz2n232DdhSy)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it by passing the iterator and the size of the `vector` and [`std::ostream_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator) to `std::copy_n`.

```
std::copy_n(v.begin(), v.size(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
```